# Use batch_size in model_fn in skflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, skflow

I need to create a random variable inside my `model_fn()`, having shape `[batch_size, 20]`.

I do not want to pass `batch_size` as an argument, because then I cannot use a different batch size for prediction.

Removing the parts which do not concern this question, my model_fn() is:

```
def model(inp, out):
    eps = tf.random_normal([batch_size, 20], 0, 1, name="eps"))) # batch_size is the 
    # value I do not want to hardcode

    # dummy example
    predictions = tf.add(inp, eps)
    return predictions, 1
```

if I replace `[batch_size, 20]` by `inp.get_shape()`, I get

```
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, 20)
```

when running `myclf.setup_training()`.

If I try

```
def model(inp, out):
    batch_size = tf.placeholder("float", [])
    eps = tf.random_normal([batch_size.eval(), 20], 0, 1, name="eps")))

    # dummy example
    predictions = tf.add(inp, eps)
    return predictions, 1
```

I get `ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using eval(): No default session is registered. Use`with sess.as_default()`or pass an explicit session to eval(session=sess)` (understandably, because I have not provided a feed_dict)

How can I access the value of `batch_size` inside `model_fn()`, while remaining able to change it during prediction?

Comment: Try using None instead of batch_size.eval()

Comment: @Aaron I tried, but it gives me `TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the difference between `Tensor.get_shape()` and `tf.shape(Tensor)`. The latter works:

```
eps = tf.random_normal(tf.shape(inp), 0, 1, name="eps")))
```

As mentionned in Tensorflow 0.8 FAQ:

> **How do I build a graph that works with variable batch sizes?**
>
> It is often useful to build a graph that works with variable batch
>   sizes, for example so that the same code can be used for (mini-)batch
>   training, and single-instance inference. The resulting graph can be
>   saved as a protocol buffer and imported into another program.
>
> When building a variable-size graph, the most important thing to
>   remember is not to encode the batch size as a Python constant, but
>   instead to use a symbolic Tensor to represent it. The following tips
>   may be useful:
>
> Use batch_size = tf.shape(input)[0] to extract the batch dimension
>   from a Tensor called input, and store it in a Tensor called
>   batch_size.
>
> Use tf.reduce_mean() instead of tf.reduce_sum(...) / batch_size.
>
> If you use placeholders for feeding input, you can specify a variable
>   batch dimension by creating the placeholder with tf.placeholder(...,
>   shape=[None, ...]). The None element of the shape corresponds to a
>   variable-sized dimension.